# Quasar QSelect with multiselect, does not show async selected values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using latest quasar (1.15.3).

I have a QSelect component with multiselect set to true
and i'm getting data from the server. I expect the multi select to be updated with the selected values, but it only happens when I click it.

Here is the select code:

```
<q-select
    v-model="form.scopes"
    ref="scopesSelect"
    required
    class="q-mt-md full-width"
    label="Role Application Scopes"
    placeholder="Select one or more application scope(s)"
    data-testid="scope-select"
    option-value="value"
    option-label="label"
    multiple
    emit-value
    use-input
    use-chips
    :options="filteredScopes"
    :rules="[
      val => (val && val.length) || 'Role Application scope is required'
    ]"
    @filter="onFilterByScope"
  />
```

`form.scopes` contains `["Global","Default"]` so I expect these values to show as selected.

`filteredScopes` has this form:

```
[
   {label: "Global", value:"Global"}
   ...
]
```

This is how the page looks after I loaded the data from the server:

[image]

as you can see, the last select is not populated, but as soon as I click it, It show the selected values:

[image]

Currently the only way I found around it is by using an ugly hack:

```
hackToCauseMultiselectListToRenderSelectedValues() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.scopesSelect.focus();
  });

  setTimeout(() => this.$refs.roleName.focus(), 500);
},
```

So I'm manually focusing the select component, which also shows the dropdown, and then, after a while I focus the input at the top so the dropdown will go away.

I tried other methods like `this.$refs.scopesSelect.refresh();` but nothing worked :(

Would love to hear any idea.

Comment: Seems to work in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zYozqMP?editors=1010). Can you update the codepen to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @tony19 Thank you for the investment, I can't reproduce it in the pen either. Our case is actually a bit more complex since we have a component wrapping the q-select so I'm not using it directly (as you can see from the image, we use a custom template), I guess I'll have to do some digging